# Python error when exporting from qgis2web

Tags: qgis, qgis2web

I'm a beginner with qgis2web. I've tried to export a very simple map to make some practice, but Python shows the following error when trying to export. I've tried several times with different projects, but always failed.

```
Si è verificato un errore durante l'esecuzione del codice Python: 

BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe 
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/giuliaalboraci/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/maindialog.py", line 357, in saveMap
    webbrowser.open_new_tab(self.exporter.destinationUrl())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/webbrowser.py", line 68, in open_new_tab
    return open(url, 2)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/webbrowser.py", line 60, in open
    if browser.open(url, new, autoraise):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/webbrowser.py", line 606, in open
    rc = osapipe.close()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 995, in close
    self._stream.close()
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe


Versione Python: 3.6.8 (v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 02:04:31) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] 
Versione di QGIS: 3.4.7-Madeira Madeira, exported 

Percorso Python:
/Users/giuliaalboraci/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/networks
/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python
/Users/giuliaalboraci/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python
/Users/giuliaalboraci/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins
/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins
/Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/E/Python/3.6
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
/Users/giuliaalboraci/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python
/Users/giuliaalboraci/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/kmltools/libs
.
/Users/giuliaalboraci/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/joinmultiplelines
/Users/giuliaalboraci/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web
/Users/giuliaalboraci/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins
/Users/giuliaalboraci/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/mmqgis/forms
/Users/giuliaalboraci/Documents/Mappa Bologna/GIS
```

Could someone please help?

Comment: What does this mean *"Si è verificato un errore durante l'esecuzione del codice Python:"* ?

Comment: Your QGIS 3.4.7 is quite old. Current QGIS is 3.22 LTR or 3.24 current. Try updating, maybe that solves the error by itself.